# civi crm database schema

Tags: crm, civicrm

I'm investigating this application for a client.  Can someone send me a link to the schema so I can review what data is stored and how difficult it might be to convert from the existing application?  Also, can SQL Server be used as the BE?

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated CiviCRM channel where you would be best to target other questions https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/

For the schema, try https://doc.symbiotic.coop/dev/civicrm/latest/schema/index.html which is in the Answer at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19704/er-diagram-for-the-latest-civicrm-foreign-key-in-structure-test-cases-plans